# setEditText without the id

Tags: android

I want to call a specific EditText which is named after my matrice location, I mean, building the id for EditText with a string and setting it afterwards.
now I need to set the editText01 text in the layout, normally I would set like this:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText01);

editText01.setText("WHATEVER I NEED");
```

BUT, I can't access by the id name because I have to access a specific one, based on the row, column so it needs to be something like:

```
String row = "0"; // row index converted to string, for example

String column = "1"; // column index converted to string, for example

String string = "editText" + row + column; // string should be editText01

string.setText("WHATEVER I NEED"); //WRONG LINE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create id using String to call specific edit text use this code

```
  String viewID="editText" + row + column; // string should be editText01
     //id for view
    int resID= getResources().getIdentifier(viewID,"id", getPackageName()); 
    EditText edit= (EditText) findViewById(resID);
    edit.setText("WHATEVER I NEED");
```

In this code create Edittext id using string

Comment: Debugged your code, in this line edit return "null", which means, the conversion from string to int was incorrect.
EditText edit= (EditText) findViewById(resID);

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that I'm trying to pass data to another activity, which I need to work on with "putextra" and "intent". You solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**: 
In your case, you can check the `R.java` class and get the id of editText.
But I recommend solution 2 to avoid use reflection in your code.

Here is the code of using reflection.

```
private int findIdByName(String nameOfId) {
   try {
        Class IdFolder = Class.forName(context.getPackageName()+".R$id");
        Field field = IdFolder.getField(nameOfId);
        return (int) field.get(null);
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "can not find R.java class");
         e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "the field of resource not defined");
         e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "can not get static field in R");
         e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClassCastException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "the value of field is not integer");
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return 0;
}

String idName = "editText" + row + column; // string should be editText01
int id = findIdByName(idName);
if (id != 0)
   EditText editText01 = findViewById(id);
```

**Solution 2**: 
You must create `EditText` in `for` and set an id for each one. Then put each `EditText` into an array list.

So every time that you want access to an `EditText` you have all object in the array list. for more understanding what I said see below:

```
List<EditText> list = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
   EditText editText = new EditText(context);
   editText.setId("editText" + row + column);
   list.add(editText);
}
```

and when you want an `EditText` you can call this method:

```
private EditText findEditText(String id) {
   for (EditText editText: list)
      if (editText.getId().equals(id)
         return editText;

   return null;
}
```

also don't forget to add each EditText in the view. For example you can put a LinearLayout in your layout and after create each `EditText` add that into LinearLayout. something like this put in the `for`:

```
LinearLayout linear = findViewById(R.id.linear);
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
//...
   linear.addView(editText)
/...
}
```

If you do not understand what I said, feel free to put the comment and ask questions.

Comment: I'll relate to your second solution. It is a solution, but every time I'm clicking the button a long for is being executed, not efficient.

Comment: @ShayPanuilov if you mean the `for` that creates `EditText`s, you are wrong because of that call only once, and if you mean the `for` that search for an `EditText` in  `findEditText` method. don't worry about that

Answer (score 0):

You should set the tags for all edit text like

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
et.setTag(<some tag >);
```

then make use to findViewByTag API to retrieve the edit text

```
   EditText et = (EditText)findViewByTag(<tag name>);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this"?
"this" is the whole question, how to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getIdentifier()`:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("editText" + row + column, "id", context.getPackageName());
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(id);
et.setText("WHATEVER I NEED");
```

You can omit `context` inside an activity class.